# Move Azure WebJob to from one Webapp to another Web app

Tags: azure-webjobs

I have created a simple webjob and deployed it on my test webapp on my trial azure portal to learn few things.

As part of this learning I would like to move this webjob to an another webapp in the same azure portal without redeploying it through the visual studio. How it is achievable?

Any help is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the section [`Copying files directly in their proper location`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-Jobs#copying-files-directly-in-their-proper-location) of the Kudu wiki, I think you can try to move your Azure webjob via FTP from one webapp to the other.

The steps for moving as below via FTP tool.

1. Ready for a ftp tool which can connect two ftp services of Azure Webapp simultaneously, such as [FTP Rush](http://www.wftpserver.com/ftprush.htm).
2. Copy the ftp connection strings of the two webapps, then refer to the article to move the webjob files & dirs in the directory `wwwroot/app_data/jobs/...` between two instances.

Meanwhile, I think you can try to use GitHub to redeploy the same webjob for the other webapp if using the continuous deployment for Azure, please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-continous-deployment/. Please keep the same structure of undering the webapp directory `wwwroot` with the GitHub repository.

Comment: Peter is right.  As long as you have a Web App to move it to, you just need the files under the wwwroot/app_data/jobs directory to match and the WebJob Host will see the new files as jobs and start running them (unless you include a job.disable file).  Ftp is a good way but you can also use the Kudu tool and drag and drop the files using a modern browser (not IE though).

Comment: Thanks peter. too late to thank you back but it has helped to understand what i need to do.